# How to destroy ekko lightbox before binding new images

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am using **ekko lightbox** for display the gallery images in my project. I need to destroy the old images before binding new image. Anyone can please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code, because without code, we can't understand what you want and we can't hepl you

Comment: posting your code will help others find something for you

Comment: This is my code : $(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightboxgallary"]:not([data-gallery="navigateTo"])', 'click', function (event) {
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        $(this).ekkoLightbox({
                                            height: 700,
                                            width: 700                                            
                                        });
                                    });